# How can I stop or exit batch file

Tags: batch-file

I've created a simple batch file to reorganize a set of files/folders. It's working as it should, but I need to print the results to a log file, and now, I can't stop it, please help me.

```
@echo off 
cls
del/f c:\SWSETUP\info.txt
systeminfo.exe >>c:\SWSETUP\info.txt
find /i "System Model:" c:\SWSETUP\info.txt
find /i "OS Version" c:\SWSETUP\info.txt
del/f c:\SWSETUP\log.txt
netsh mbn show interfaces >> c:\SWSETUP\log.txt
find /i "Model" c:\SWSETUP\log.txt
find /i "Firmware Version" c:\SWSETUP\log.txt
test.bat >> result.txt
@GOTO :EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

If your batch file is called `test.bat`, it is calling itself in

```
test.bat >> result.txt
```

so it will never end. Try with something like

```dos
@echo off
    >"info.txt" systeminfo.exe 
    >"log.txt"  netsh mbn show interfaces 
    >"result.txt" (
        findstr /l /i /c:"System Model:" /c:"OS Version" "info.txt"
        findstr /l /i /c:"Model" /c:"Firmware Version" "log.txt"
    )
```

Or, if the `info.txt` and `log.txt` are not needed, only `result.txt`, you can use

```dos
@echo off
>"result.txt" (
    systeminfo.exe            | findstr /l /i /c:"System Model:" /c:"OS Version"
    netsh mbn show interfaces | findstr /l /i /c:"Model" /c:"Firmware Version" 
)
```

Comment: Thanks! that's I want answer.